# To prove, $\nabla.(\nabla\phi \times \nabla\psi)$ =0

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, vector-fields

Please Help me solving the problem  using levi-cevita symbol :
Prove That, $\nabla.(\nabla\phi \times \nabla\psi)$ =0 where $\phi =\phi(x,y,z)$ & $\psi=\psi(x,y,z)$

Comment: Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our meta site for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better. I would advise you to migrate the question to MathsSE.

Answer (score 4):

By definition of the cross product and gradient operators, and summing over repeated indices we have, $$\nabla . (\nabla \phi \times \nabla \psi) = \partial_i (\epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j \phi \,\partial_k \psi) = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i \partial_j \phi \,\partial_k \psi+ \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j \phi \, \partial_i \partial_k \psi.$$ But both terms vanish, since for example looking at the first term, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is anti-symmetric under exchange of $i$ and $j$ whereas $\partial_i \partial_j \phi$ is symmetric.